# Hibernate/resume fails after adding SSD on Debian 7

Tags: linux, ssd, hibernate

My Debian 7 system used to hibernate and resume just fine; then I added an SSD as follows: 1) added SSD (on SATA 1), 2) updated /etc/uswsusp.conf (use UUID for swap partition), 3) copied /usr and /opt to SSD partitions, 4) modified /etc/fstab to mount /usr & /opt partitions, 5) ran update-grub2.

And resume fails after hibernate. It used to work. If I unplug the SSD, it still works (after removing new partitions from fstab).

hibernate.log doesn't indicate a problem. The failure causes journal recovery on all partitions except /.

Here's my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=1796cdd5-7bf3-4334-a5cb-7aed099e57f7   /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#SSD 
UUID=74c7d1c9-0807-4f40-99bf-55766f9ecaeb   /usr            ext4    commit=100,noatime        0       1
UUID=e70718c9-ee8a-4679-a486-be8e5be2821a   /opt            ext4    commit=100,noatime        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=488cfe1d-439f-45b7-82d0-fb3b31e9b1ee   /home           ext3    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=abec2610-c8d7-4a2c-98f7-cfa2b338fb9b   none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0                                    /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
/dev/sdd1                                   /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
UUID=2ffe2063-c413-4cce-9007-a79f1ae9a122   /mnt/2TB        ext3    defaults        0       2
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the SSD from SATA 1 to SATA 5, reran update-initranfs -u and things work.  I don't quite understand why this should work since all disks are referenced by UUID but resume now works.